# KSOAP Add Custome Type for a Node

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am using Android ksoap2 library to consume a SOAP web service.

One node in the request looks like..

```
//some more nodes
.............
    <dateVals i:type="n0:dateTimeArray">
                <item i:type="d:dateTime">1988-09-17</item>
    </dateVals>
..........
//some more nodes
```

This how I am trying

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Commons.NAMESPACE,
            Commons.METHOD_NAME_REGISTER);

SoapObject dateParent = new SoapObject("", "dateVals");
        PropertyInfo dobItem = new PropertyInfo();

        dobItem.setName("item");
        dobItem.setValue("1988-09-09");
        dobItem.setType("d:dateTime");

        dateParent.addProperty(dobItem);

        request.addProperty("dateVals", dateParent);
```

A error throws from the server, as it is not the expected format.

Where I am doing wrong?

EDIT

Complete request, here `HashMap<String, String> values;` comes from other class.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Commons.NAMESPACE,
                Commons.METHOD_NAME_REGISTER);

        request.addProperty("authUser", Commons.AUTH_USER);
        request.addProperty("authKey", Commons.AUTH_KEY);
        request.addProperty("storeName", Commons.STORE_NAME);
        request.addProperty("sms", "true");

        request.addProperty("firstName", values.get("firstName"));
        request.addProperty("lastName", values.get("lastName"));
        request.addProperty("sex", values.get("sex"));
        request.addProperty("language", values.get("language"));
        request.addProperty("email", values.get("email"));

        SoapObject dateParent = new SoapObject("", "dateVals");
        PropertyInfo dobItem = new PropertyInfo();

        dobItem.setName("item");
        dobItem.setValue(values.get("dateVals"));
        dobItem.setType("d:dateTime");

        dateParent.addProperty(dobItem);

        request.addProperty("dateVals", dateParent);

        request.addProperty("phoneNumber", values.get("phoneNumber"));
        request.addProperty("password", values.get("password"));

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);



        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(
                Commons.URL_NEW_MEMBER);
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;

        try {

            Commons.lastTouchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            httpTransportSE.call(
                    Commons.NAMESPACE.concat(Commons.METHOD_NAME_REGISTER),
                    envelope);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

            responseCode = Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty("return")
                    .toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseCode = -1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Try `dobItem.setType(dateTimeObject.getType());` where you have a `dateTime` class with `dateTimeObject`.

Comment: @swayam But I do not have any class for `dateTime`

Comment: Can you share the full soap request?

Comment: then you would need to create one kvmSerializable.

Comment: @AmitGupta yes I can! but is it relevant to the problem?

Comment: This should work for you. https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem yes! I faced the similar problem once, so it will easy to find the problem.

Comment: @swayam Thanks. but that is like a `mapper` class for the custom objects. But it is not what I am looking for, as you can see there it writes `arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;` but I want type="d:dateTime"

Comment: @AmitGupta I add complete code.

Comment: `arg2.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS` or something like that. I am not sure. Try Cntrl + Space on PropertyInfo. You will get the exact name for the user defined class.

Comment: Actually I am online from my mobile right now and hence cannot give you a proper detailed answer. Sorry for that. If you could wait until the evening, I can write the answer properly instead of comments.

Comment: @swayam can you able to see the problem?

Answer (score 3):

// For any method Namespace is required. So it should not be black. So i changed here.

```
SoapObject dateParent = new SoapObject(Commons.NAMESPACE, "dateVals");
    PropertyInfo dobItem = new PropertyInfo();

    dobItem.setName("item");
    dobItem.setValue(values.get("dateVals"));
    dobItem.setType(PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS);
    or
     dobItem.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
    dateParent.addProperty(dobItem);
```

// Use addSoapObject() to add any child SoapObject to main request Object.

```
 request.addSoapObject(dateParent);
```

// Add these two line while forming Envelop

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
```

Hope this will help you.
It will be more easy if you will share full soap request(XML format)

Comment: main thing is how I can achieve  `i:type="d:dateTime"`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem there is no specific type for dateTime. Either PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS or PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS should work for you. Can u plz share the WSDL or XML for your required method.

Comment: here I add the relevant part of the WSDL https://www.dropbox.com/s/yyzemezruv4uux8/wsdl.xml

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem there is a software called SoapUi. http://www.soapui.org/ . You can install it and create a project with your WSDL url. Once done you can check all the method with the all the fields.

Comment: Yes I have it. and use for testing. Thanks